# Add Open Extension for Microsoft Graph through the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a multi-tenant application with Azure Active Directory. Each of the clients that are using my application need to specify a couple of configuration details that are necessary for its functioning. Nothing complex, just some key-value pairs.

Looking at the documentation of the API for Microsoft Graph it seems that open extensions are a good place to store this kind of information. The only issue with this is that this needs to be done through the API, so each of the tenants would need to do so through an API call.

Is it possible to specify those open extensions through the Azure web portal without passing through the API? I am aware that there is also the Graph Explorer, but I am looking for something that the tenants can do easily on their own, so even suggestions on other methods to have those couple of key-value pairs would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want to add open extension to the AD App or SP? But it looks both are not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#supported-resources

Comment: @JoyWang Eventually, I could add it to the organization, the represents the Azure AD that the user is signed into